# Sorting answers in blade LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

I have this code, and I want to sort them by order, I have the `order` column in database which always takes `1, 2, 3, 4` and I want the answers to be in that order how can I do this on laravel blade .

```
<div class="form-group" id="group-form-id">
    <label id="correct_answer" style="color: #00a65a;">
        @lang('test-results.correct_answer'):

        <div style="line-height: 8px; padding-top: 5px;">
            <?php $i=1; ?>
            @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
                @if($answer->order)
                    <span id="test_span">
                        <br>
                        <em style="padding-right: 10px; color: #999;">
                            {{ $i }}.
                        </em>
                        {!! $answer->text !!}
                    </span>
                    <hr style="width: 500%;border-top: 1px solid rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.37);">
                @endif
                <?php $i++; ?>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try this :

```
<div class="form-group" id="group-form-id">
                    <label id="correct_answer" style="color: #00a65a;">
                        @lang('test-results.correct_answer'):
                        <div style="line-height: 8px; padding-top: 5px;">
                            <?php $i=1; ?>
                        @foreach($question->answers->sortBy('order') as $answer)
                                @if($answer->order)

                                <span id="test_span"><br><em style="padding-right: 10px; color: #999;">{{ $i }}.</em>{!! $answer->text !!}</span>
                            <hr style="width: 500%;border-top: 1px solid rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.37);">
                            @endif
                            <?php $i++; ?>
                        @endforeach
                        </div>
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: @ylli Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

In the controller when you return the questions you can use query builders orderBy(order). See this documentation: [Laravel Query Builder - Order By](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the answers collection:

```
$question->answers->sortBy('order')
```

Check [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortby)